# facebook SDK doesn't work in android

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to integrate facebook SDK into my android project.

I've extracted  the facebook sdk and imported into eclipse.
So in order to use the sdk I had set up a new android project with the setting 
of minSDK->8 and build target of 4.4. The problem is that when I add the facebook sdk into my 
android project's library the sdk is not added. If it was added, there should be a check mark instead of X.

I read through the facebook developers instruction but it doesn't work.I would be glad if you can help me out.

Comment: I don't get it. I imported the facebookSDK as a existing project and added the library and at first you can see the green check mark and after I press apply and ok button it may seem fine but in reality the library has not been added. When I go back to the properties and see the library I can see a X error . The only thing that works is the facebook sample apps. I really don't get the point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure that the SDK folder and your project folder are in same location

Comment: Can I ask you a question? I had extracted the facebookSDK from a zip file but how can I how can I implement this extracted folder into a android project? I'm still  not sure, where and which folder I should place the facebookSDK into.

Comment: copy the extracted folder into the same folder of your project. then do the same procedure as you already did